# Issue using Auto Layout Constraints Programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, autolayout

I have this situation:

[image]

I want this:

The black view is at X distance between violet view and if I tap I button in the violet view the violet view's height reduces(or increase) and I want that the black view is at the same X distance between violet view.
For this reason I write this code:

For button event that increase or reduce the violet's view I use this method:

```
@IBAction func tapOpenButton(){

      self.altezza.constant = self.altezza.constant + 20

    }
    @IBAction func tapCloseButton(){

        self.altezza.constant = self.altezza.constant - 20

    }
```

where `altezza` is a  `NSLayoutConstraint`

The both views are in a scrollview and I set constraint by code in this way:

```
var newView = blackView
    var view = violetView
         let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

            let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 120)
                       let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
            let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)

        self.altra.addConstraints([horizontalConstraint,verticalConstraint, widthConstraint, heightConstraint])
```

`altra` is the scrollview where both views are

My problem is that the distance between the violet view and black view is not the same when I reduce or increase violet's height , in particular , for example , when I increase the violet view's height , violet view goes under the black view.
I'm new in auto layout by code.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works in place of your heightConstaint

```
let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pinning the views by `centerY`, set the top of the black view to the bottom of the purple one with a margin.

```
let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
```